# Is `loadup.el` hard-coded, such that `-nl` (aka --no-loadup) is futile?

Tags: start-up

I would like to create my own `startup.el`, and it seems that `loadup.el` is what causes `startup` to do its thing -- i.e., `(load "startup")`.  I see that an option for starting Emacs is `-nl` or `--no-loadup`; however, neither of those have any affect on OSX.  Is `loadup.el` perhaps hard-coded into the executable such that a startup option to the contrary has no effect?

I have tried:

```
/absolute/path/to/Emacs -nl
```

and

```
/absolute/path/to/Emacs --no-loadup
```

I am using OSX, and have a very recent version of Emacs Trunk built from the master branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct; this option is not relevant to the fully-built `emacs` executable, because that library (and the many others it pulls in with it) are pre-loaded in that executable.

You can, if you so wish, create your own custom executable by modifying the sources before the dumping process occurs.

Refer to:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Building Emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you -- I just read through the reference you pointed out a couple of times and I'll read it again a few more.  Of particular interest was the `preloaded-file-list` which appears to contain the libraries specified in `loadup.el`.  I'm a little hesitant to completely turn Emacs into my own monstrosity, so I'll probably create a custom build that gives me a user option to go with the stock loadup, or my custom loadup.  I see that some of the ingredients of `startup.el` are mandatory for a successful build, so I'll have to locate all of them . . .  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For cross-reference purposes: This question reminded me to write up a similar answer to [How does Emacs manage to start instantaneously with many el-files?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/15247/454)