# Building emacs without certain packages/components

Tags: build

I'm a longtime Emacs user, and I've decided to take the plunge and build it myself, because I can, and because maybe I'd like to choose a different graphical toolkit. By the by, is there any way, when compiling Emacs, to only compile certain portions?

As in, I know I'm never going to use the IRC client, the mail client, the two browsers, etc. So is there a way for me to build Emacs without those components that I don't need and will only be taking up binary space?

Comment: Many (most?) of the Emacs components are written in Emacs Lisp. The source files are byte-compiled, but they aren't built-in to the binary, and are only loaded when needed. You could, in theory, save a few seconds during installation by not byte-compiling components you don't want to use. But I expect the time you would save would be far less than the time spent figuring out how to do this very non-standard install. And after you've compiled Emacs, there would be no difference in how long it takes to load the program, or any performance benefit.

Comment: Also, the binary on my machine is only 27MB - it's actually pretty modestly sized by modern standards.

Answer (score 6):

The vast bulk of Emacs libraries are *not* included in the `emacs` executable; so if you never use them, they are merely taking up a little space on the filesystem. With modern hard disk sizes, I think it's *extremely* unlikely to be worth your time deleting any of them to reclaim space.

The only elisp libraries which are directly included in the `emacs` executable are the ones loaded by `loadup.el` (see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16521 for details).